# Using all functionality of OOP in three different classes

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have a homework to do, I need to create three classes Student, Profesor what inherits from a class list of faculty and I dont know how to chain all OOP functionality (and must), I need to use templates and not a builtin list I need to alocate dynamic list of objects of students and profesors order by departament, I need to use static virtual methods namespace and operators rewrite, why I will need usage of virtual metods there? And usage of namespace?
I started this, but I'm in trouble, how to get a good structure to use all of the OOP functionality?
Thanks for tips!

**Skiny header sourcecode:**

```
ifndef FACULTATE_H
#define FACULTATE_H

class Facultate
{
    char *nume;
    list<Profesor*> profesori;
    list<Student*> studenti;
    public:
    void addProfesor();
    void addStudent();

    Facultate();
    virtual ~Facultate();
    Facultate(const Facultate& other);
    Facultate& operator=(const Facultate& other);
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& O, const Facultate &F);
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // FACULTATE_H
```

Comment: You should start with strict problem formulation, I think.

Comment: Start by rewriting your question. You've got about 80 words in that first run-on sentence, and they don't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I dont know what structure of classes should be. How can object faculty itself can be a list of each other two object lists??

Comment: Do not confuse language features with OOP paradigm.

Comment: Closing until you follow Caleb's advice and rewrite the question. It's difficult to help you unless we understand exactly what you're asking and exactly what you do not understand. Use the [edit] link underneath the tags to get started. Remember, closing is a temporary state, so do not be discouraged! Questions can be re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to organize this.

Here is one layout:

```
class Person;
class Student : public Person;
class Facultate : public Person;
class Teacher : public Facultate;
class Staff : public Facultate;
```

The Person class would contain attributes common to Students and Teachers, such as first and last name.